# Ohio duty to report (2921.22) : Does it apply to victims?

Tags: ohio

I was researching duty to report a crime, and saw that Ohio was one of the few places that had a general duty to report.  So I read the state statute at http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/2921.22

Nowhere did I see an exception for the victim of a crime.   So,  if you are the victim of a crime that is a felony in Ohio, and you choose not to report it,  can you be charged under this law?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the law or the drafter's notes indicating that victims are exempt from the law's requirements. But I've also searched through about a hundred 2921.22 cases and haven't found a single one where a victim was prosecuted for failing to report.